# Angled elements over entire viewport

Tags: html, css

How would you realize a angled layout with 3 elements? Which technologies would you use? Canvas? Transform? Skew? JS or CSS only? It has to be responsive in some kind :)

I tried different ways but i'm not sure. Here is one:

```js
/* ======================================================== */
/* 'resize window' event handler
/* ======================================================== */

var addEvent = function(object, type, callback) {
    if (object == null || typeof(object) == 'undefined') return;
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } else if (object.attachEvent) {
        object.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
    } else {
        object['on' + type] = callback;
    }
};

addEvent(window, 'resize', function(event) {
    setSliceSize();
    consoleLog();
});

/* ======================================================== */
/* get window width
/* ======================================================== */

function getWidth() {
    if (self.innerWidth) {
        return self.innerWidth;
    }

    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
        return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    }

    if (document.body) {
        return document.body.clientWidth;
    }
}

/* ======================================================== */
/* get window height
/* ======================================================== */

function getHeight() {
    if (self.innerHeight) {
        return self.innerHeight;
    }

    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }

    if (document.body) {
        return document.body.clientHeight;
    }
}

/* ======================================================== */
/* get window square root 
/* ======================================================== */

function getSquareRoot() {
 return Math.sqrt((Math.pow(getWidth(), 2)) + (Math.pow(getHeight(), 2)) );
}

/* ======================================================== */
/* set dimensions of squares
/* ======================================================== */

function setSliceSize() {
 var slices = document.getElementsByClassName('slice');
 for (var i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
  slices[i].style.width = getSquareRoot() + 'px';
  slices[i].style.height = getSquareRoot() + 'px';
 }

 var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');
 rotator.style.width = getSquareRoot() * 2 + 'px';
 rotator.style.height = getSquareRoot() * 2 + 'px';
 rotator.style.marginLeft = - getSquareRoot() + 'px';
 rotator.style.marginTop = - getSquareRoot() + 'px';
}

function deg45() {

}

function consoleLog() {
 console.log(getWidth()); console.log(getHeight());
 console.log(getSquareRoot());
}

window.onload = function(){
 setSliceSize();
 consoleLog();
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

/* ======================================================== */
/*  rotator & slices
/* ======================================================== */

#rotator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 30%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.slice {
    position: relative;
}

#first-third {
    background: red;
    margin-top: 30%;
    float: left;
}

#second-third {
    background: green;
    float: right;
}

#third-third {
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}

/* ======================================================== */
/*  ...
/* ======================================================== */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>x</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="wrap">
  <div id="rotator">
      <div id="first-third" class="slice"></div>
   <div id="second-third" class="slice"></div>
   <div id="third-third" class="slice"></div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is this a good solution?

Thank you ;)

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I voted to close this. If you want it to be kept open, please make it more specific.

Comment: It should be a full screen layout and without scrolling.
The 3 'slices' should contain about equal sizes.

Comment: Answering questions like _Is this a good solution?_ is off topic here at SO. Code review is most likely a better place. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/